# javascript for loop with recursion and return value example

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert json object into array of path string but not getting expected result.
Don't know might be other way to achieve the same but tried using for loop  and lodash `isObject` and `isEmpty` for validate object like below.

**Input Json:**

```
    const json = {
  "info": {
    "account": {}
  },
  "info2": {
    "address": {
      "mobile": {
        "phone": null
      }
    },
    "contact": {
      "first": {}
    }
  }
}
```

**javascript code:**

```
var pathArray = this.convertJsonToArrayOfPathString(json);
    console.log(pathArray);
convertJsonToArrayOfPathString(json, pathArray = [], path = '') {
    const keys = Object.keys(json);
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      const key = keys[i];
      path = path ? path + '.' + key : key;

      if (_.isObject(json[key]) && !_.isEmpty(json[key])) {
        this.convertJsonToArrayOfPathString(json[key], pathArray, path);
      }
      else {
        pathArray.push(path)
        path = ''
      }
    }
    return pathArray;
  }
```

**expected output:**

```
[
      "info.account",
      "info2.address.mobile.phone",
      "info2.contact.first"
    ]
```

could you please any help.
thanks.

Comment: There is no `foreach` in your code example. Are you posting the correct version? There is no need for `isObject` and `isEmpty` code if you use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: @PeterKrebs updated question heading..but i am not sure whether using correct or not but what all i want expected output format for any input json.

Comment: Ok. BTW you forgot `function` before the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const json = {
  "info": {
    "account": {}
  },
  "info2": {
    "address": {
      "mobile": {
        "phone": null
      }
    },
    "contact": {
      "first": {}
    }
  }
};
var pathArray = convertJsonToArrayOfPathString(json);
console.log(pathArray);
function convertJsonToArrayOfPathString(json, pathArray = [], path = '') {
    const keys = Object.keys(json);
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      const key = keys[i];
      const newPath = path ? path + '.' + key : key;
      const value = json[key];
      if (typeof value === 'object' &&
            !Array.isArray(value) &&
            value !== null && Object.keys(value).length>0) {
        convertJsonToArrayOfPathString(json[key], pathArray, newPath);
      }
      else {
        pathArray.push(newPath);
      }
    }
    return pathArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const json = {
  "info": {
    "account": {}
  },
  "info2": {
    "address": {
      "mobile": {
        "phone": null
      }
    },
    "contact": {
      "first": {}
    }
  }
}

var pathArray = convertJsonToArrayOfPathString(json);
console.log(pathArray);


function convertJsonToArrayOfPathString(json, pathArray = [], path = '') 
{
    Object.keys(json).forEach( key =>
    {
      const p = path ? path + '.' + key : key;
      var test = !json[key] || Object.keys( json[key]).length < 1 || Array.isArray( json[key]) ||
                typeof  json[key] !== 'object';
      return  test ? 
              pathArray.push(p) :
              this.convertJsonToArrayOfPathString(json[key], pathArray, p);
    });
    
    return pathArray;
}
```